# In Drupal, Drag on Timeline not working for private mp3 file

Tags: google-chrome, drupal-7, drupal-8, audio-player, mediaelement.js

I have uploaded a mp3 file into a **private folder**. What I see, when I place the url in the browser or in any audio player like MediaElement.js, it plays, but I can't drag the timeline in Chrome browser. When I click on timeline or drag it, it always starts from 0 seconds. In FireFox its working okay. Alternately if I upload in a **public folder**, in both Chrome and FireFox, it works and I can drag the timeline.

For this, Drag on timeline working both in Chrome and FireFox:
https://bbsradio.com/sites/default/files/Symphony-No-6-1st-movement.mp3

For this, Drag on timeline NOT working in Chrome BUT working in FireFox:
https://bbsradio.com/system/files/audio_dirs_five/Symphony-No-6-1st-movement.mp3

I was testing on Drupal 7 but I think it would be same in Drupal 8 and 9 also. Can anyone help me out on this issue?

An example of private upload here, https://bbsradio.com/podcast/unlimited-life-february-17-2021

Comment: the first 2 links you posted give me a "Page not found". The third link, I can play the audio and dragging works fine for me in Chrome Version 89.0.4389.72

Comment: thank you for checking, just fixed the issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed now. Drupal core issue for resume able download. Check this posing:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3201455